# .NET Core Blazor App: How to pass data between pages?

Tags: html, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, blazor

I just started learning how to make websites with using Blazor template. But I don't know how to pass the data from one page to another. It is a bit different than .NET CORE MVC web application and I couldn't find an example for this.

```
    <p>Solve This problem: @rnd1 * @rnd2 = ?</p>

    <input type="text" name="result" bind="@result" />
    <input type="button" onclick="@calculate" value="Submit" />
```

I want to send the value in my textbox to the another page. How can I do this?

Comment: if you want to pass multiple parameters on a query string you can check https://stackoverflow.com/a/57914502/3093561

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72180076/how-to-pass-an-object-from-one-page-component-to-another-page-component-in-a-ne/72183754#72183754

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You can pass it as a parameter.

In the page you want to navigate to, add the parameter to your route:

```cs
@page "/navigatetopage/{myvalue}"
```

and make sure the parameter exists in that page:

```cs
[Parameter]
private string myvalue{ get; set; }
```

In the same page you can pick that up in:

```cs
protected override void OnParametersSet()
{
    //the param will be set now
    var test = myvalue;
}
```

Now in your start page make sure to navigate to the second page including the value:

```
uriHelper.NavigateTo($"/navigatetopage/{result}");
```

That uriHelper needs to be injected like this:

```
@inject Microsoft.AspNetCore.Blazor.Services.IUriHelper uriHelper
```

**UPDATE PREVIEW-9**
on preview-9 you should use navigationManager instead of uriHelper, it also has a `NavigateTo` method

```
@inject Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.NavigationManager navigationManager
```

Comment: Is there a reason `myvalue` is not camelCased? Not being snarky, just wondering if there's something with case-sensitivity when it comes to the url parameters?

Comment: No, you could make it camelCase as long as you also adjust it on both places (route and parameter)

Comment: Is there a way to pass `object` to the next page while doing navigation?  I tried `Parameter` and `CascadeParameter` but couldn't access it.

Comment: Not using a parameter, as it ends up on the url.

Comment: Documentation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/routing?view=aspnetcore-3.1#route-parameters

Comment: Only problem with this approach is that optional parameters aren't supported as shown in docs above.

Comment: I believe you can add multiple routes, so you could add one without the param

Comment: Is there a way to do this if you wanted to pass a custom model?

Comment: What if I want to pass a parameter to some target page but allow that page to be reloaded (without passing the parameters again) Any way to "clear" url parameters?

Comment: @JeremyS.  Passing entire data models between pages is bad as it can open the way for malicious attacks or stolen data. When you pass parameters via the URL it is best to use something that references the data (usually just some kind of number) and not the data itself.  Then you can use that reference to retrieve the data you need for the new page. Also consider using Data Transfer Objects (DTOs) in this process.

Comment: @TysonGibby how would you pass such a DTO?

Answer (score 4):

More recent versions support the following:

The page you are navigating from:

```html
<NavLink href="/somepage/1">Navigate to page 1</NavLink>
```

The page you are navigating to:

```html
@page "/somepage/{childId:int}"

<h1>Some Page</h1>

<p role="status">Current child: @childId</p>

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public int childId { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I personally prefer to add query string to the url.

For example when I want to pre-select tab when page is loaded:

Call the url like `http://localhost:5000/profile?TabIndex=2`

In your code you can parse this using [NavigationManager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.components.navigationmanager?view=aspnetcore-5.0) and [QueryHelpers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.webutilities.queryhelpers?view=aspnetcore-5.0)

Add `using Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities;`

Then override one of the lifecycle methods and parse the query parameter

```
protected override void OnAfterRender(bool firstRender)
    {
        if (firstRender)
        {
            Uri uri = this.Nav.ToAbsoluteUri(this.Nav.Uri);
            if (QueryHelpers.ParseQuery(uri.Query).TryGetValue("TabIndex", out StringValues values))
            {
                if (values.SafeAny())
                {
                    _ = int.TryParse(values.First(), out int index);
                    this.TabIndex = index;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I got an error while testing Flores answer in the page were we passing a data

Below is the current Page

```
@inject Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.NavigationManager navigationManager

Int64 Id {get;set;}

<MudMenuItem @onclick="@(() => NextPage(@Id))">Next Page</MudMenuItem>

//So Here I am passing the ID which is long
private void NextPage(Int64 Id){
    navigationManager.NavigateTo($"/secondPage/{Id}");
}
```

Second Page

```
Instead of using -Id only you need to cast it to long or else it throws an error

-From
@page "/pettyCashAuditTrail/{Id}"
-To
@page "/pettyCashAuditTrail/{Id:long}"

[Parameter] public Int64 Id{ get; set; }
```