# Multiple query string parameters in Blazor routing

Tags: .net-core, blazor

I have multiple working examples in my current project of retrieving 1 query parameter from the url however when trying to follow the same convention for multiple url params, I'm receiving the following error in the chrome debugger console:

```
Error: System.InvalidOperationException: 'Router' cannot find any component with a route for '/confirmemail'.
```

my page route is defined as:

```
@page "/confirmemail/{Token}/{UserId}"
```

and the `@functions{...}` section contains the following properties:

```
[Parameter]
string Token { get; set; }
[Parameter]
string UserId { get; set; }
```

I am trying to retrieve the query string parameters for a url that looks like this:

`http://localhost:50466/confirmemail?Token=SomeReallyLargeToken&UserId=SomeGuidUserId`

How can I achieve this?

Comment: This `/confirmemail/{Token}/{UserId}` doesn't contain query parameters, it contains route parameters, these are two completely different things. You should be using query parameters, so take out `/{Token}/{UserId}` from your `@page` directive and follow Antonio Correia's answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Could you try?

```
http://localhost:50466/confirmemail/SomeReallyLargeToken/SomeGuidUserId
```

I think it should work.

Answer (score 29):

For anyone interested in how to pass and get the parameters in the query string style

`http://localhost:50466/confirmemail?Token=SomeReallyLargeToken&UserId=SomeGuidUserId`

the page route doesn't change

`@page "/confirmemail/"`

and you should get the parameters like

```cs
protected override void OnInitialized()
{
     var uri = navigationManager.ToAbsoluteUri(navigationManager.Uri); //you can use IURIHelper for older versions

     if(QueryHelpers.ParseQuery(uri.Query).TryGetValue("Token", out var token))
     {
         var token_par = token.First();
     }

     if(QueryHelpers.ParseQuery(uri.Query).TryGetValue("UserId", out var userid))
     {
         var userid_par = userid.First();
     }
}
```

Remember to add the following

```cs
@inject NavigationManager navigationManager
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities @*for QueryHelpers*@
```

I'm using preview-9

Comment: In my case this was exactly what I needed to know. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: Why do you use TryGetValue and not just ...["Token"]?

Comment: Just to add to the answer above, if you're using wasm, note that you need to install nuget package `Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities` in client project (since it's not part of default blazor package.)

Comment: This is a MUCH better answer, I don't know why this isn't the accepted one.

Comment: @JensMander `TryGetValue` avoids `KeyNotFoundException` if the query parameter is not present: it is common behavior for `Dictionary<,>` objects.

Answer (score 14):

A new answer to an old question: At the time of January 2022, query string parameters can be processed with the complementary attribute SupplyParameterFromQuery.

```
[Parameter] [SupplyParameterFromQuery]
public string Token { get; set; }
[Parameter] [SupplyParameterFromQuery]
public string UserId { get; set; }
```

Comment: Thanks. I already had `[SupplyParameterFromQuery]`, but it was not enough. `[Parameter]` is needed as well.

Answer (score 2):

This ( `/{Token}/{UserId}` ) is not a pattern of query string. It is a part of the route template url(route parameters). This is a query string: `?Token=SomeReallyLargeToken&UserId=SomeGuidUserId`.

I'm not sure about it, right now, but this may work: `http://localhost:50466/confirmemail/SomeReallyLargeToken/SomeGuidUserId`

If you wish to access **query parameters** (not route parameters), you want to use the IUriHelper like this:

```
var uri = new Uri(UriHelper.GetAbsoluteUri());
```

Note that you should parse the returned value... I once saw a utility created by the Blazor community that does it.

Hope this helps...

Comment: This works well but only if both parameters are non-nullable... If both of them are nullable then you should use Dirk Brokhaus answer

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use the extension method presented here:

https://chrissainty.com/working-with-query-strings-in-blazor/

I just put more types:

```
public static class NavigationManagerExtensions
{
    public static bool TryGetQueryString<T>(this NavigationManager navManager, string key, out T value)
    {
        var uri = navManager.ToAbsoluteUri(navManager.Uri);

        if (QueryHelpers.ParseQuery(uri.Query).TryGetValue(key, out var valueFromQueryString))
        {
            if (typeof(T) == typeof(int) && int.TryParse(valueFromQueryString, out var valueAsInt))
            {
                value = (T)(object)valueAsInt;
                return true;
            }

            if (typeof(T) == typeof(int?) && int.TryParse(valueFromQueryString, out var valueAsNullableInt))
            {
                value = (T)(object)valueAsNullableInt;
                return true;
            }

            if (typeof(T) == typeof(bool) && bool.TryParse(valueFromQueryString, out var valueAsBool))
            {
                value = (T)(object)valueAsBool;
                return true;
            }

            if (typeof(T) == typeof(bool?) && bool.TryParse(valueFromQueryString, out var valueAsNullableBool))
            {
                value = (T)(object)valueAsNullableBool;
                return true;
            }

            if (typeof(T) == typeof(string))
            {
                value = (T)(object)valueFromQueryString.ToString();
                return true;
            }

            if (typeof(T) == typeof(decimal) && decimal.TryParse(valueFromQueryString, out var valueAsDecimal))
            {
                value = (T)(object)valueAsDecimal;
                return true;
            }

            if (typeof(T) == typeof(decimal?) && decimal.TryParse(valueFromQueryString, out var valueAsNullableDecimal))
            {
                value = (T)(object)valueAsNullableDecimal;
                return true;
            }

        }

        value = default;
        return false;
    }
}
```

regarding the: "Dealing with updates to query string values" part... I did like so:

```
<a class="dropdown-item" @onclick='() => GotoLink("thepage?intValue=0&boolValue=true&stringValue=blahBlah")'>goGoGo</a>
```

and the GotoLink method is this:

```
private void GotoLink(string url)
{
    NavManager.NavigateTo(url, forceLoad: true);
}
```

by the way the route of the component is cleaner:

```
@page "/ThePage"
```