# How to send value from edit form between pages in Blazor

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor

So, I have an application in Blazor Server and I have two pages. On the first page the user introduces his Username and after he clicks the login button I want to show on the second page the Username he introduced. I tried with routing parameters, but I don't know if that's the right way because I'm new to Blazor.

```
@page "/firstPage"

<EditForm Model="@user" OnValidSubmit="@Login">
                        <label class="form-control-label text-muted">Username</label> <input type="text" id="username" name="username" @bind="user.Username"> 

                        <button class="btn-block btn-color">Login</button>
</EditForm>


@page "/secondPage"

//here I want to show the username from the first page
```

Comment: There are many options but I would suggest to read about TempData in .net.

Comment: Are you using the built-in authentication with ASP.NET Core Identity? Where are the user details stored? In an EF Core managed database?

Comment: @AmalK no, i'm not using the built-in authentication, I'm using custom authentication and yes, I have a User class and an EF Core managed database where the data is stored

Comment: If you only want to pass Username,you can pass it as a parameter in url,refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51226405/net-core-blazor-app-how-to-pass-data-between-pages).

Answer (score 0):

Your `user` model needs to be in a scoped data service.

You can do something like this:

```
namespace Blazor.App
{
     // Add to services as a scoped service
    public class UserDataService
    {
        public User User { get; set; } = new User();
    }

    public class User
    {
        public string UserName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Then inject into the pages:

```
@page "/firstPage"
<EditForm Model="@DataService.User" OnValidSubmit="@Login">
                        <label class="form-control-label text-muted">Username</label> <input type="text" id="username" name="username" @bind="DataService.User.Username"> 

                        <button class="btn-block btn-color">Login</button>
</EditForm>
@code {
[Inject] private UserDataService DataService {get; set;}
}
```

```
@page "/SecondPage"
<div>@DataService.User.UserName</div>
@code {
[Inject] private UserDataService DataService {get; set;}
}
```

Comment: I already have the User class and a UserService class to manage the data from a database, sorry I didn't specified that

Comment: [Polite] So where's your problem?  You point your edit form to the user class??  You can have say a `LoginAttemptUserName` property in your service, which you use to do the authentication and populate your user class.

Answer (score 0):

If your application is relatively simple (good question what simple means for someone)... But in that case you can do a few things:

- Instead of using pages use components. Since Balzor is a component based framework. So on the same page you can have multiple components (`<component1 />` and `<component2 />`) and only render/show the one which needed. And components can have parameters with one or two-was binding. So you can read the user value form `<component1 />` and pass it into `<component2 />`
- Also you can use the suggested custom services to store data.

**Both solutions works for really simply apps. But when you need pass data around into multiple places then it becomes a nightmare**... Your application state will be a mess. So **recommend to check `immutability` and `state store`**, etc. React has Flux extension a very similar is available for Blazor as well called **[Fluxor](https://github.com/mrpmorris/Fluxor). Recommend to check their docs and try to use it even for "medium" complex applications.**