# Blazor - Sending multiple data between pages

Tags: html, blazor

I was looking at this question: [.NET Core Blazor App: How to pass data between pages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51226405/net-core-blazor-app-how-to-pass-data-between-pages)

But it didn't quite answer my question: How do I send multiple data from one page to another, where that data is shown live (or in real-time) on another page?
The page where it is sent from, one user is writing a not too big amount of data, and I want that data shown on the second page, where another user can see it, but not write it.

Hope you understand and can help me, thanks.

**EDIT:**

I have tried with a observer pattern implementation, where I in the first page declare the Subject, and in the second page declare the Observer. But how do I link those together?

```
Subject STest = new Subject(newValue);

Observer OTest = new Observer("User1", STest);
```

But the "STest" doesn't exist in current context.

Comment: I assume it can not be done by passing it as a parameter?

Comment: I think you are searching for something named `observer pattern`. Search in internet and you will find a lot of examples

Comment: Ok, so I have implemented the observer and subject files. I guess I should in the first page declare the subject and, and in the second page the observer. But how do I link those together? It says the name doesn't exist in current context, because the observer and subject is declared in two different files.

Comment: You probably want a Dependency Injection.  Look up "Blazor Singleton Service" if the data is common among all users, or "Blazor Scoped Service" if it's for the current client only.

Comment: So I'm not supposed to do a observer pattern implementation, or is just another way of doing it?